# Using already computed element

Tags: c#, linq

I find myself repeating calculations within a linq statements and I was wondering whether I can access already computed elements somehow. This is what I m doing:

```
var result = testdata.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, a.commodity, a.timestep.Year })
                     .Select(g => new EndResult
                            {
                                rundate = rundate.ToShortDateString(),
                                price = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.price : 0) / g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? 1 : 0),
                                valueposition = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.position * a.price : 0) / (g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.price : 0) / g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? 1 : 0)),

                            }).ToList();
```

Which works fine.

This is what I would like to be doing:

```
var result = testdata.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, a.commodity, a.timestep.Year })
                     .Select(g => new EndResult
                            {
                                rundate = rundate.ToShortDateString(),
                                price = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.price : 0) / g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? 1 : 0),
                                valueposition = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.position * a.price : 0) / price,           
                            }).ToList();
```

where the price is the price I computed just after rundate. Can I access this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select an anonymous type first to store this value:

```
result = testdata.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, a.commodity, a.timestep.Year })
.Select(g => new { 
    rundate = rundate.ToShortDateString(), 
    price = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.price : 0) / g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? 1 : 0),
    group = g
})
.Select(x => new EndResult
{
    rundate = x.rundate,
    price = x.price,
    valueposition = x.group.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.position * x.price : 0) / x.price
}).ToList();
```

Another way is using "real" code:

```
result = testdata.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, a.commodity, a.timestep.Year })
.Select(g => { 
    var price = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.price : 0) / g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? 1 : 0);
    EndResult endRes = new EndResult { 
        rundate = rundate.ToShortDateString(),
        price = price,
        valueposition = x.group.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.position * price : 0) / price)
    };
    return endRes;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you. this should be faster but eats more memory. correct?

Comment: @nik: note that i've added another apporach. Both should be faster and don't need more memory since it's just a "loop"-variable.

Comment: are you saying my code is not real!? I m hurt...:) only kidding thanks for your help!

Comment: @nik: no, but you can use any code in a LINQ query if you use an anonymous method(i hope that this is the correct term). You need to use the `return` statement then.

Answer (score 2):

By using the [query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) (`from`), you can use the [let](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause:

```
 var result = (from g in  testdata.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, a.commodity, a.timestep.Year })
               let price = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.price : 0) / g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? 1 : 0)
               select new EndResult
               {
                   rundate = rundate.ToShortDateString(),
                   price = price,
                   valueposition = g.Sum(a => (a.timestep.ispeak()) ? a.position * a.price : 0) / price,
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: "from syntax" -> [query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) ;-)

Comment: haha, true, just thought 'from' would be clearer for indicating the difference. Thanks for including the linq link :)